# Migrate Datas to Salesforce Org without same namespace

Tags: namespace, jitterbit, field-mapping

I am using Jitterbit Harmony to migrate datas from one salesforce org to another org. Source org has no namespace but second one has namespaces(as xyz_customobject__c). In that situation, I must mapping fields by manually. Is there any way to map fields automatically?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, the must match or you must manually map them. See their [support forum q/a](https://getsatisfaction.com/dataloader/topics/help_regarding_the_data_extract_and_auto_map_the_fields).

**Question**:

> Hi I want to extract the data from SF and need to map the fields to
>   Columns present in the Target file which are different from the field
>   names.is it possible??

**Answer**:

> Auto-map only works when the field names are the same. You can do a
>   manual mapping inside the transformation.